# Remove output from add-apt-repository

Tags: command-line, apt, scripts

I'm trying to write a shell script that will automatically set-up a LAMP stack for me.  One of the lines I have in the script is:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable >> /tmp/output.txt
```

But try as I may it always outputs the following content:

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpf0k2tr/secring.gpg' created
etc........
```

I would like there to be *no* output to be displayed to the screen when I run this command to add this ppa to my repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use output redirection to `/dev/null` and include `stderr` output.

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable > /dev/null 2>&1
```

- The `2>&1` will tell Bash to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.
- The `command > file` stanza will redirect `stdout` to a file, in this case `/dev/null`.
- `/dev/null` is the black hole of Linux - you won't be able to recovery anything from there.

Result: full silent execution of your command.

In your updated question you seem to log all output to a file. In that case you can just append the `2>&1` to your current line:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable >> /tmp/output.txt 2>&1
```

This is because you were looking at the `stderr` output being printed on the terminal, which you need to redirect to the log as well (otherwise you will miss out on all errors!).

Comment: @Braiam This is based on the command the OP provided in his question. I assume it works for him and his script is running as `root` here. **The question is about suppression of output**, not about a *non-working* command.

Comment: "stderr to stdout" ah!  That was the trick.  I though all output to the console was the same.  Thanks for highlighting that not all output is actually the same.

Comment: @gertvdijk remember that people tend to do copy-paste without knowing how, what, when, where, etc ;).