# Remove output from add-apt-repository, without hiding true errors

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, scripts, log

I'm trying to script that will automatically install some packages.  One of the lines I have in the script is:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng -y > /dev/null
```

But try as I may it always outputs the following content:

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpf0k2tr/secring.gpg' created
etc........
```

I would like there to be *no* output to be displayed to the screen when I run this command to add this ppa to my repository.

I know that I may [hide entire stderr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341473/remove-output-from-add-apt-repository) but it will hide also true problems - I want to get rid of only of routine log.

Answer (score 2):

The `>` redirects only `sdtout` stream, while it's obvious that `gpg` messages go to `stderr` (otherwise they would be hidden). Thus there is no way to redirect the `gpg` messages  without affecting the error messages also.

But it's possible to redirect stderr through pipe and filter the output with awk or grep, ignoring all lines that start with `gpg`.

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep -v '^gpg'
```

Comment: I am hoping that some sort of parameter may affect gpg behaviour (`--no-spurious-stderr` or something). Filtering is probably something that may work but I will probably use something more strict (to avoid catching messages like `gpg completely failed because...`)

Comment: If you have read the manpage for `apt-add-repository`, you probably saw that there's not that many options available , so nope - nothing can be suggested in the parameters.    What's your ultimate goal ? You don't want the output take up the whole screen ? In that case why not redirect to file ?

Comment: I want my script to print only errors and be silent in case of success. It is almost successful (just `pip install numpy` before adding `-q` used to print entire screens of garbage) but there are still some issues, pointless output of `apt-add-repository` is one of them.

Comment: And, yes - I am aware that manpage for apt-add-repository has no obvious solution. Otherwise I would not be asking this question.

Comment: Well that's the best i could offer. Maybe others can come up with better idea. One other thing i can think of is to redirect stderr to tmp file, making program itself silent, but test exit code for success. If exit code indicates error, then print the error file.